# Django work with group

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have 3 blocks in my page. How make that first users group can see first block? second-second, third-third.

example:

{% if usergroup = first%}
{% block first %}

...

Comment: essentially you have the idea; if you want people here to provide you with specific code for your app, then  you need to supply your code. your user model that handles the usergroup attribute, and the view code/template you are trying to do.

Comment: Look. I created users group in admin-panel.

That authorized users can see block, im write in view.py

...
args['username'] = auth.get_user(request).username
...
in main.html
...
{%if username%}

Answer (score 0):

`User` model has many-to-many relation with `Group` model that has unique `name` field. I would leave logic for checking user group in view and pass simple context variable with group name to template like in your example `usergroup` and check it as you already mentioned with `if` and `elif` template tags.

Comment: pls, write as it looks. I second day dont comlit this problem.

Comment: Do you need view or template?

Comment: Need view.I will be grateful

Comment: @DimonKudimon check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sepulchered/e41da7cc3a506c5a23cd)